# Firebase database update not working when app is minimized

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have done this :

```
 private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            currentLatitude = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("latitude"));
            currentLongitude = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("longitude"));


            if(!java.util.Objects.equals(m_Text, "")) {//if ph number not blank
                User user = new User();

                user.setLatitude(currentLatitude);
                user.setLongitude(currentLongitude);
                //  user.setPhone(m_Text);
                mFirebaseInstance.getReference(m_Text).setValue(user);


            }




        }
    };
```

the co ordinates are being updated as expected irrespective of app is in foreground or not, but the `mFirebaseInstance.getReference(m_Text).setValue(user);`not posting to firebase when app is minimized, othrwise working properly. Any solutions on how to achieve it?

Comment: Possibly caused by Doze or [App-Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#understand_app_standby).  When you observe this behavior is the device plugged-in?  Is the screen on?  What is the API level of the device?

Comment: Irrespective of whether the device (api 24 and 23 both tested on real device) is plugged in or not, app is in foreground/active or not or in partial doze the receiver receives the updated variables regularly, as per the breakpoint observations, but the update to firebase method only works when the app is in foreground...is there any workaround??

Comment: As there is no solution suggested by the experts over here or it may be unseen or overlooked by them, I would like to ask whether I can put the whole firebase initialization and method call to the background service if that would work. Any help or example regarding that would also be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like this BroadcastReceiver is defined in an Activity.  In what Activity lifecycle methods do you register/unregister the receiver?

Comment: dynamically at onstart registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Whereabouts.str_receiver));

BTW how can that relate to my problem as I am receiving the broadcast 100% properly?

Comment: And where is it unregistered, `onStop()`?

Comment: not unregistered it onStop or onPause, does that really matter? as firebase method inside it not working while the rest of the broadcast receiver does? previously was onPause unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

Comment: Yes, it matters.  Because you never unregister the receiver, it will continue to be called after your activity is destroyed.  It also causes a memory leak. The memory for the dead activity cannot be reclaimed because the  receiver is still registered. Receivers should always be [registered/unregistered in the appropriate lifecycle methods](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#context-registered_receivers).

Comment: but how does that relate to my problem ? even if I  unregister onPause my problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root issue after a while, the app needs permission for background data on the device in order to post data to firebase database, enabled it/added permission by Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BACKGROUND_DATA_RESTRICTIONS_SETTINGS intent and it just works fine!